# "Counter" in "countersteering" an adverb or adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the word "countersteering" what is the role of the word "counter"? Is it an adverb or adjective? I am asking because the words are not separated. So I suppose it is an adverb.

Additionally what category of a word this is? Is it a compound verb or something else?

Comment: counter adverb _in a way that opposes something_ (Cambridge Dictionary).

Comment: Adjectives and adverbs are parts of speech. _Counter-_ in _countersteering_ is not a word, so it does not have a part of speech.

Comment: I think the question is legit for someone who does not know about compounds and prefixes. And it's a good idea to be less snobby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> countersteer: *counter-* + steer

where *counter-* is a **prefix** to the verb of steer.

[Source](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/countersteer)

Comment: Yes, it is. Exactly, a prefix.

Comment: @Lambie this is where I was sort of confused. This is after all a compound verb, because I can say "I countersteered into that turn". But when looking at the formation of the word is it built out of an adverb or a "prefix"? Looking up the word "over" in the dictionary there are separate entries for adverb and prefix. Is it when an adverb forms a single word compound verb we treat it as a prefix and when it forms a two word phrasal verb it is an adverb?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Ok, I see what is confusing you. counter is a **prefix**, just like post, pre, ab and many others and appears in words like counterclaim and countersuit. It means "against" and comes from Anglo-French contre. The role is to express the idea of steering in a different direction from the one you are going in.

Answer (score 1):

It does in fact exist:

[countersteering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countersteering)

It is a noun.
We don't separate out words from existing words.
Worldwide is one word so in it world and wide don't have functions. The word is an adjective, unlike the one that was asked about.

Countersteering is used by single-track vehicle operators, such as cyclists and motorcyclists, to initiate a turn toward a given direction by momentarily steering counter to the desired direction ("steer left to turn right").

Comment: The question is about the function of "counter", not "countersteering". Nobody has debated the existence of the word "countersteering"

Comment: @gotube Frankly, I think you go over board sometimes. At least I put him on the right track. I think my answer is totally appropriate.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you're trying to say here, or perhaps you subscribe to a particular school of thought, but in general we *do* analyse compounds in terms of the parts of speech of their constituents: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound And if you don't fancy taking wikipedia's word for it, what about Cambridge Dictionary? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/compounds

Comment: @Lambie and thank you for being so polite in return. I wasn't commenting on you, I was commenting on your answer. Since when did comments under other people's answers have any bearing on our own answers? Now as you say, your answer was aimed at addressing the general statement. Are you not saying that we don't break compounds down and analyse their parts of speech? Because actually we do, which is why I linked to examples of sources where compounds are discussed in that way. Which means the OP is a legitimate question and an answer saying we don't look at compounds like that is wrong

Comment: Now you might then go on to observe that many compounds are more than the sum of their parts, or that part of the compound may not (now) exist in its own right (cranberry morphemes) or that (as in the case of 'cupboard') the meaning of the compound has drifted somewhat from its original and those are fascinating discussions to have, but they're secondary discussions to the fundamental truth that a blackberry is a berry that's black and the compound is an adjective-noun compound

Comment: Now I went out of my way to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that's what you meant, although you were a bit heavy handed in overlooking the fact that real edited linguistics textbooks introduce compounds by describing the parts of speech of their components. And in return you were just rude.

Comment: @Au101 You do not understand. I entered my answer and to be fair, I didn't edit it to win. I could have and did not. I was not rude at all. I explained what happened and why. That's all. Countersteer is not a compound word. It is a word with a prefix. That is very different from a compound noun. And finally, in compounds the words don't have functions, which is what the OP thought. They have meanings.

Comment: See this is why I commented, it wasn't an attack on you, it's because I don't agree. If I go to my first year linguistics textbook, a prefix is defined as a type of affix, which is defined as a 'bound morpheme'. A bound morpheme 'must be attached to other morphemes, e.g., -ly, -ed, non-'. Counter is a free morpheme. But you could say it functions as a prefix here and its part of speech is irrelevant and that'd be fine.

Comment: No, to paraphrase said textbook, in compound words the POS of the head determines the POS of the compound, n+adj=adj (e.g. headstrong); v+n=n (e.g. pickpocket). This analysis is fundamental to the analysis of compounds in linguistics and is why I commented. But I commented assuming that's what you were trying to say (or you were trying to say that this is not helpful to a learner and only of interest to a pedantic linguist).

Whereas you responded with "why don't you go read[...]?" and I don't need to be shown examples of reference works doing what I say we don't do "Thanks." That's rude.

Comment: @Au101 I meant for you to read it so you could see how it complemented my answer. That's all.